# Redirect URLs with a # in .htaccess

Tags: htaccess, redirects, hash

On one of my sites I get 404s because some scripts are fetching all URLs from the start page as *raw* URLs, so they include the `#` in the URL. Normal browsers don’t ever send that part to the server, but these scripts do.

This is how a typical requests URL looks like:

```
/2014/how-to-manage-wordpress-multisite-imports-with-wp-cli/#comments
```

The `#` is not URL encoded.

I tried both following methods:

```
RedirectMatch 301 \#comments       /
```

and

```
RewriteRule #(.+)$ /? [L,R=301]
```

Both without success, the rules don’t catch these requests, because the `#` starts a comment. The referer and the user-agent fields are empty.

What should I do?

Comment: Since this is a "script" (not a browser) which is sending these malformed URLs, is a 404 not the correct response?

Comment: I was thinking that "400 Bad Request" would be the appropriate response.

Comment: "Normal browsers don’t ever send that part to the server, but these scripts do." - Are you absolutely sure? Just because you tell JS to request that URL doesn't mean the browser will do it. Have you checked the Network tab in Firefox/Chrome Dev Tools?

Comment: @DisgruntledGoat My question is about requests that I logged _on the server_, not something my browser sends. I don’t even know how to reproduce these requests, because wget, curl and PHP strip everything from the `#` on.

Answer (score 4):

From [the mod_rewrite documentation](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/rewrite/flags.html#flag_ne) you need to use the `NE` (no escape) flag when your rewrite rule has a hash:

```
RewriteRule #(.+)$ /? [L,R=301,NE]
```

You commented that the `NE` flag may only apply to the target URL and not the rewrite pattern.   If that is the case, another approach would be to escape the `#` sign. [mod_rewrite supports `\x` style escape sequences](http://mod-rewrite.org/book/regular_expressions.html).   The escape sequence for `#` would be `\x23`.  So your rewrite rule could be:

```
RewriteRule \x23.+$ / [L,R=301]
```

If you want to test a solution, you can do so with `telnet` on the command line.  Use the command line `telnet example.com 80` to open a socket to your webserver.   Then make a simple request like this:

```
GET /#test HTTP/1.0
Host: example.com
```

Followed by an extra new line.

Comment: I have read that as if `[NE]` is for the target URL only, not for the rewrite pattern. Will try it.

Comment: ...and, as the link suggests, _flags_ apply to mod_rewrite, not mod_alias. However, I suspect the "fragment identifier" part is stripped from the URL that is matched by the `RewriteRule` pattern (just like the query string). You could try `RewriteCond` and test against `%{QUERY_STRING}` or `%{THE_REQUEST}`?

Comment: You are right, w3d.  I put the flag on the wrong rule.   I've edited my answer now.

Comment: `\x23` doesn’t seem to work too. I will contact the hoster and report back when I get some results.

Comment: @toscho How are you testing this? Or are you just waiting for one of these "invalid" requests coming through? You say the "`#` is not URL encoded" (presumably looking at your logs), however, an unencoded `#` in the URL is strictly invalid, so even if you are able to match the `#` it would not be correct to return a valid response (but also, who/what are you returning a response to?). You say your server is responding with a 404... what URL is your script seeing in your (custom) 404; if your custom 404 is being called at all?

Comment: @w3d Unfortunately, I haven’t found a way to make such requests, so I have to wait. The URL is that in my question. The 404 is served by WordPress. I want to avoid that and catch these requests before WordPress is loaded. A simple 400 with just one line of output should be enough.

Comment: I've added info on how you can test it.