# Mod_rewrite rule for Magento2 to access sku with # in

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, apache2, c#, restful

I have an issue similar to this question [Redirect URLs with a # in .htaccess](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/76047/redirect-urls-with-a-in-htaccess)

I'm trying to access Magento 2 api at /rest/all/V1/products/sku. This works for majority of products but some have a # symbol in their structure ie #123456 or #98754. I keep getting a Bad request returned form the server.

I'm unsure how to format the rewrite rule I wish to pass it through to the api but retain the # symbol. the Requested is created by Restsharp.

```
Rewritecond %{HTTP_HOST}/rest/all/V1/products/
RewriteRule #(.+)$ #$1 [L,NE]
RewriteRule \x23(.+)$ #$1 [L,NE]
```

Comment: How does your question differ from the points discussed in the linked question? What URLs _exactly_ are you trying to rewrite from/to?

Comment: think I've managed to resolve by changing # to %23 when compiling the request string.  tried this before but it never worked..but testing again now and it is returning the correct json

Comment: Glad you got it resolved. You should add that as an answer (and later accept it) to possibly help other readers and to remove the question from the unanswered question queue. Thanks.